# Problem with checking GET

Tags: php

I am trying to check $GET array. But i have some problem.

URL: http:// www.my.qqq/?s=lessons

Code:

```
if (!empty($_GET['s'])) {
 echo '1';
}
else {
 echo '0';
}
```

Result: 0

But if i use http:// www.my.qqq/index.php?s=lessons

But script is working normaly if i am using both adresses except GET.

Why GET is not working with this url http:// www.my.qqq/?s=lessons and working with http:// www.my.qqq/index.php?s=lessons?

PS. 
OS: Windows

My problem was RewriteRule ^([a-z_]*)/?$ index.php?s=$1

If somebody knows: How to make http:// www.my.qqq/?s=lessons and http:// www.my.qqq/lessons/ available in one time?

Answer: [QSA] flag at the end of Rewrite rule ^([a-z_]*)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA]

Thanx all for help!

Comment: What happens if you do `http:// www.my.qqq/?s=lessons`? Do you have a different index file in the directory (e.g. index.htm)?

Comment: What's the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the PHP script of that context? Is there a redirect that removes the GET parameters from the request URI?

Comment: when i do http:// www.my.qqq/?s=lessons then i have same result as on http:// www.my.qqq/index.php?s=lessons except GET.

Comment: Does the script run on both occations and do you have any rewrite rules that might change the url when using /? form

Comment: Is mod_rewrite involved, especially rewrite rules without QSA flag?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which web server you are using.  This looks to be a problem with your URL rewriting rules; for Apache, ensure that `mod_rewrite` preserves the query string (the portion after the `?`).